# Cannot get the value and assign to a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have try to use the following to get the MD5 for the txt. Output it to other file and rescan. dumb method but seem it return nothing every time.

```
(certutil -hashfile %targetfolder%\%baseName%%n%\inventory_2.0.1.bck MD5 | find /v "hash" | find /v "") > rootfs_md5
set /p texte =< D:\script\rootfs_md5
echo %texte%
```

Also try the following method without temp file but seem also return null

```
for /f %%i in (certutil -hashfile %targetfolder%\%baseName%%n%\inventory_2.0.1.bck MD5 | find /v "hash") do set VAR=%%i
echo %VAR%
```

any reason for that

Comment: Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG " to a value of " N". Remove the spaces from **both** sides of the `=`.. In the `for /f`, the pipe redirector needs to be escaped. Use `^|`, not `|`. The command needs to be single-quoted, so `( ' certutil…hash" ' )` [the spaces surrounding the single-quote are not required - they are there for emphasis).

Comment: programming window is very weird....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's examples for each of the methods you attempted.

Using a temporary file:

```bash
@Set "FileHash="
@%SystemRoot%\System32\certutil.exe -HashFile "%targetfolder%\%baseName%%n%\inventory_2.0.1.bck" MD5 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V ":" 1>"D:\script\rootfs_md5"
@If Not ErrorLevel 1 Set /P "FileHash=" 0<"D:\script\rootfs_md5"
@If Defined FileHash Del "D:\script\rootfs_md5" & Echo %FileHash: =%
```

Without temporary file:

```bash
@Set "FileHash="
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\certutil.exe -HashFile "%targetfolder%\%baseName%%n%\inventory_2.0.1.bck" MD5 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V ":"') Do @Set "FileHash=%%G"
@If Defined FileHash Echo %FileHash: =%
```